# Will a promise not to watch/read anime be broken if I inadvertently see it in videos unrelated to anime?

Tags: halal-haram, oaths

I made a promise to Allah not to watch/read any anime that has sexual content in it. I have kept my promise over the past year, but recently I found myself whenever I watch any video, I fear that I might see something that will break my promise.

Will my promise be broken if I see 'anime' related images in videos that are unrelated to anime, like in a reality TV show?

Comment: Maybe elaborating a bit might help. I don't quite understand your situation.

Comment: For sure, my promise was not to watch any anime that were sexual in nature, however, as time went on, I started to become excessive in checking tv shows/videos/books to see if there was any animated character, (not just anime related, but anything that was cartoonish) to the point I would pause a video multiple times just to check if it was that in order not to break my promise....

Comment: A 30minute video would turn into an 1hr just because of me checking everything in that scene. I think this just wasawa and doubt but I dont know how to reverse this. I get anxious when i watching something since I might see something related to anime that might break my promise.

Comment: You don't really need a promise to keep you from watching that. It is probably haram by itself. And it is not a bad thing to not watch tv shows.

Comment: I would keep my promise, literally, and not watch "any anime that were sexual in nature".

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I understand that I dont really need to watch Tv shows, but when I watch anything, I have the urge to check everything thing about it to ensure theres nothing that could potentially break the promise. I feel like this is more about doubt in breaking the promise.

Edit. Sorry posted this before seeing the other comment.

Comment: Its not clear what your "promise" is. An oath in Allah's name is different from some commitment you made to yourself or to another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not make anything harder than it needs to be. Unless something is a sin, keep promises to their spirit. Nothing more, nothing less.

In general, anything done by mistake is not a sin. As long as you were not doing or watching anything sinful that led you to do or watch what you promised that you would not, it is not a sin (for example an ad popped up when you were doing homework for school):

> "**Verily actions are by intentions**, and for every person is what he intended. So the one whose hijrah was to Allah and His Messenger, then his hijrah was to Allah and His Messenger. And the one whose hijrah was for the world to gain from it, or a woman to marry her, then his hijrah was to what he made hijrah for." (Bukhari & Muslim)

As soon as you are led into it, you must quickly remember your promise and leave the sin immediately. But, the important part is you were not doing a sin which caused you to break the promise.